# How to make a stair railing like this one?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender, I only used Maya some years ago...

I'm trying to make the stair in the picture but I don't know how to do the railing. I know I have to use a curve and then extrude a circle in it but how to?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks for those links. I think I was using the wrong curve.