# How do I make an object move along a path in either direction?

Tags: constraints, path

I'm trying to make a garage door open or close by rolling up or down like they usually do. I know how to make an object follow a path in one direction along a curve using constraints, but I need it to move in both directions. Is there a way to do this?

Also, when I try using the Follow Path constraint with a NURBS Path, the object attached to it only goes about a third of the way along the path and then lifts off and heads out into space. By reducing the number of keyframes, I can get it to follow the path just long enough to roll up like I want it to, but that seems to be a poor way to do this, and it still only allows the object to go in one direction.

Comment: "in either direction" what does that mean?

Comment: Please include a Blender screen capture to clarify your success and problems.

Comment: A screen capture won't help much, since I don't know how to capture this problem.

Comment: I want to move an object in both directions along a curved path. I.e. move it in one direction along a curve, as well as move it back in the other direction. Garage doors go up and down along the same path. That's what I'm trying to simulate.

Comment: There's a better way to do this, using array modifier and curve modifiet, I'm away from my computer now, but you can find lots of answers using this method.

Comment: Also using follow path, I am sure there's an option to reverse the curve's direction.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve if you use this method, you can slide the object and it's instances along the path usig G, you can move it in both directions.

Comment: I started out trying to use the array and curve modifiers, but it didn't want to work no matter how I fiddled with it. Then I tried using the Follow Path constraint as described in countless tutorials, posts, and manuals. That only allowed me to move one object in an array, destroying the array in the process. I wanted the door to consist of panels that swiveled on the curve, but I'm stuck with having to use a single large panel that can only go one direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of garage door you are talking about.

You can start with a single plank or slat.

[image]

Then add an array modifier to replicate it on the Z axis.

[image]

Add a curve with the path you want the door to follow (it's important that the door and the path have their origins on the same place):

[image]

On the original plank add a curve modifier and select the curve as guide object:

[image]

Move the door up and down on the Z axis, and it will curve following the path.

[image]

If you are dealing with a rigid door. Then instead of the curve modifier add a Follow Path constraint. And select the curve as target. Enable "Follow Path",  Set "Up" to Y and "Forward" to -Z

[image]

Then animate the offset value:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It appears to work for me. The Follow Path constraint doesn't work well with arrays, as I've found out.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't want to work in the BGE, which was my ultimate aim. I used cegaton's method and created two actions, one opening the door and one for closing it. These are controlled by the arrow keys on the keyboard. The door moves but it doesn't follow the path of the curve any more.

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1317" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1317/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your curve. Put more frames in 'Path Animation' and tick 'Follow'.
2. Select your object. Add 'Follow the Path' in Constraints
3. Specify curve and hit 'Animate Path' button.

[image] 
[image]

UPD: "and then lifts off and heads out into space." -- make sure you don't have any animation moving your object off it's original center position. If you have two or more animations combined, affecting center point of object, it will cause all sorts of strange movement.

UPD2: Door.blend uploaded http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41938

Comment: That allows me to move it in one direction only. I want it to move back and forth, as I've tried to explain twice already.

Comment: Just resize your Nurbs Circle (the curve to follow) into the line.

Comment: I give up. Nobody is reading the question properly and I can't state it any clearer.

Comment: Blend file uploaded.

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko please consider using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files. Files in pasteall.org expire after a few weeks. Other users will not be able to learn from your answer after that.