# how to repeat an object on a path?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to model a wooden bench with planks.

The origin of the path and cube matches. I have applied the Rotation and Scale to the Cube.

I added a curve modifier and it works till now. But when I add array modifier to it, I don't get the effect. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe move the array modifier to the top?

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite Done that. It is not working.

Comment: Try using a path curve instead of a Nurbs path.

Comment: @4-K try dupliframes

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite tried that too.

Comment: Oh, wait. I think you need to either use an offset or change your fit type to fit to length.

Comment: I tried those options too. @LetTheWritersWrite

Comment: @4-K attach the file

Comment: @ateks how? Anyway I hand modeled it.

Comment: How to upload the file Go to this website http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ attach the file and paste the question url click on upload and u get the link copy that link and paste in your question

Answer (score 1):

You should move your Array Modifier above your Curve Modifier, however, you also have the wrong option selected in the Array Modifier.

Your Array Modifier is set to "Object Offset" to calculate the array copies. As the curve and your array object share an origin, this makes no sense.

**You need to untick "Object Offset" and tick "Relative offset"** instead.

Then you can either manually set the number of array objects that you need or change "Fit Type" to fit to the length of the curve (a new box will appear allowing you to select your curve).

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Had to resort to handle modeling instead.

Comment: It is totally doable with the proposed answer. The trick is that both objects have to have their origins in the same place. See this related post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52681/how-do-i-make-an-object-move-along-a-path-in-either-direction/52829#52829