# Bezier Curve as Constraint for Bones? (Rolling garage door)

Tags: bones, constraints, bezier-curves

im trying to build a rolling garage door. To connect my six panels i used bones. Now i would like to define how they can move. I want to use this for animations or stills in different positions.
I tried to connect my bones to a bezier curve but it doesn't work. I got it moving along the curve as an object but not bending around the curve. How can i make this work?

[image]

edit: i tried the curve modifier trick whick is very simple to use.
i might have to use bones instead because of the complexity of my model.
I want the Panels to use the tail which is hidden in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: this may answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path

Comment: or this one [how do I make an object move along a paht in either direction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52681/how-do-i-make-an-object-move-along-a-path-in-either-direction/52829#52829)

Comment: @moonboots: thank you. I used the version with the Vertex-Groups and it works. i will try if a hybrid solution between the curve version and Groups will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar without using bones:

[image]

Subdivide a plane so that it corresponds to the door parts (same size as the door), for instance, this:

[image]

Add a curve modifier to this plane. The plane will keep its flat parts following the curve.

Parent the door to the plane.

Add a *"surface deform"* modifier to the door targeting to the plane (and bind it). The door will stay conformed to the flat parts of the plane.

[image]

Animate the plane along its curve axis.

[image]

Comment: Cool, i just added a curve modifier to all planes/door elements of my door. I also added a parent "door" to all "elements". Now, when i move the "door" up, all elements follow the curve. Very easy solution. Thank you. - Should i document it here or upload the file?

Comment: You're free to upload the file, as you want!

Comment: As my door-panels are a little bit more complex, i used Null-Objects to group the Elements. Is there a way to link the Null-Objects to the curve? I tried to create some objects and make them parent but parenting just moves my lanels up and down, not rotating them.

Comment: @dichterDichter, could you add some pictures of it? Or you can also upload a file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the link here.

Comment: thank you very much. i added a screenshot to my initial question

Comment: Have you tried with the plane I suggested in the answer, with the cuts at the exact location of the small weels of the door (I presume this is a weel)?

Comment: ah, now i get the idea. i will try it.

Comment: So, using the plane version did not work with all my (null-) objects. But its a nice and very easy to use Version i will consider next time and make a simpler Construction. Thank you very much

Comment: If you want, upload the model so that I can give a look.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ob317kpo/ . if you have the time... I pretty new to blender, i made the step now and have to find everything. The Bones Version and yours are similar. both use a curve modifier as a base. from there, i can connect the verteces to the bones. i thought that i can connect them to the Null-Objects but it doesnt work

Comment: It was needed to join all the parts, but here is the result: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/plwNDaNm/

Comment: thank you very much.