# Steel Cables Modeling Help

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I'm after some advice on how to model a Steel cable is anyone able to point me in the right direction of an up to date or relevant tutorial, or even able to advise me on how to create a Steel cable like what could be seen on a Tank or a Ship ?

Like ones that a tank would use to tow another.

Any help and Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Close to this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73387/generate-a-repeating-mesh-pattern-without-extra-geometry

Comment: Aye it may do it, it looks the part could pull it off at a pinch, there must be a way to actually produce something to resemble a steel cable though, Appreciated none the less

Comment: If you want to model it, you can use the screw modifier, starting from some circles joined in 1 object

Comment: after doing that would it be possible to bend it without having to move individual Vertices ?

Comment: You can bend it after that using a curve modifier. You can also use a curve modifier directly using the same base shape (circles) and put this shape as bevel object, then twist the curve (ctrl+T while in edit mode for the curve).

Comment: nice one I'll give it ago

Comment: @ Lemon I took your Idea and it done wonders, Thank you so much

Comment: @lemon, can you post this as an answer so that it can be shown as solved?

Comment: @RickRiggs, done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to do that is using curves (that will allow to bend the cable if necessary).

The principle is to make a base shape which will be a slice of the cable. Then use this slice as bevel object on a curve. Once done, you can twist/tilt the curve extremity in order to twist the cable itself.

The base/slice shape :

It can be what you want (more or less detailed, for instance). The only constraint is we need to make it a curve object at the end, so that it can be used as bevel object for the final curve (the cable).

To do it quick :

- Add a circle
- Add a array modifier to the circle and choose for instance a count of 6
- Add a simple deform modifier, set it to 'bend' and set the angle to 360°

[image]

Here the inner parts are a bit stretched (due to the deform modifier). You can refine that or use another approach (again it is to do it quick here).

The result of the modifiers is a mesh, and we need a curve.

So use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to transform it to a curve (that will apply all the modifiers and convert to curve).

[image]

Now, add a curve <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then curve and bezier and set the previous object as its bevel object.

[image]

What you obtain at this step is probably to large. So scale down the bevel object and/or stretch the cable curve (in edit mode for this last, it will be better).

[image]

Now, enter edit mode for the cable curve, select one of the extremities and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to twist and move the mouse around :

[image]

The cable is deformed. It is because the origin point of the slice/circle is not at its center. So select it and transform its origin to its geometry :

[image]

Refine the result by changing the cable/curve resolution :

[image]

And so you obtain a bendable cable.

[image]

[image]

Note :

If you want to insert some additional control points to the cable, you will notice that the twist/tilt is not divided equally... unexpected behavior (for me)... so if this is needed, remove the twist/tilt and do the twist again ;) using proportional editing.

Comment: I appreciate this so much, Sorry for the late reply had a Family emergency to tend to this is definitely what I wanted to do and will add that extra touch of realism to my Tank.