# Twisting two objects like rope, without any deformation

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to render a realistically detailed cable, with the jacket stripped back. This particular cable has 2 cores which twist around each other. I have managed to do this by applying a simple deform on the Z-axis to each cylinder and using an empty as the target.

It works, technically, but the two cylinders start to deform when twisted too much, I want them to keep their original shape without thining in the middle regardless of the twist applied. I hope this makes sense?

[image: Cylinder deforms on twsit Blender 2.8].

How can this be done?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114563/how-to-create-twisted-wires-in-blender  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73649/creating-a-twisting-cable-with-multiple-parts