# How does texture mapping work in Blender?

Tags: texturing

New to Blender last month, I had mapped a rectangular image onto a
sphere using Cycles nodes.  I noticed that Blender put the seam (where
the left and right edges of the image meet) on the front of the sphere.
I wanted the seam in the back.  Rather than rotate the sphere, I decided
to rotate the texture around the sphere.

First I tried a simple Z-axis rotation of the texture.  The result was
worthy of Salvador Dali — not at all what I had expected.

Next, I tried shifting the texture by 50% of its width in the +X
direction and changing the Image Texture node's extrapolation option
from Clip to Repeat.  (See the picture below.)  The result was not
as distorted as the previous attempt but still nothing like my goal.

Obviously I was making some bad assumptions.  So I set out to figure out
exactly how transformation of textures works in Blender.  I built the
test bed pictured.  The Generated output of a Texture Coordinate node was
fed into the Vector input of a Mapping node.  That Mapping node's output
was fed through a second Mapping node (to allow multiple transforms in an
unambiguous order) and then to the Vector input of an Image Texture
node.  The Color output from the Image Texture node traveled through a
Diffuse BSDF shader node to the Material Output node.

I drew a test picture with distinctive regions, edges, and corners so I
could see what was getting mapped where.  I then projected the image
onto five test objects (cube, rectangular prism, sphere, cylinder, and
meta cube) in various ways by adjusting the transforms in the Mapping
nodes and the Image Texture node projection options.  I also did a
simple Flat projection of the image onto a rectangular plaque in the
foreground for reference.

[image: Blender window with scene, test image, and nodes]

I started with simple Flat projection and tried various multiple
transforms.  Once I had developed a model of what Blender was doing
and tested it on the Flat projection I went on to the Tube and Sphere.

So how was my original thinking wrong?  It took a long time for my
experiments to yield enlightenment because of side issues mentioned in
my answer below.  Hopefully someone else new to Blender can glance at
this question/answer and avoid losing the time I wasted.

Comment: Some related experiments on the same subject: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73769/how-do-i-get-a-better-understanding-of-the-coordinate-system-in-blender/73797#73797

Comment: Anyone wondering about texture mapping should watch Bartek Skorupa's video: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj00)

Answer (score 3):

I eventually came up with a reasonable model for the mechanism.  But
along the way I was confused by Blender's order of transforms and
its display of materials.

## Projection Model

My basic problem was that I was not considering *exactly* where the
object and the texture are located in what I will call "texture space".
Conceptually the object and texture are placed into texture space and
the surface of the object is colored according to where it intersects
the projected texture.

As a starting point for the texture mapping the object and the image are
made "the same size".  The object's bounding box (a rectangular prism in
its local coordinates) is scaled in the X, Y, and Z directions to create
a cube one unit on a side.  The cube with its distorted object is placed
in the first octant of the 3D texture space with its lower left front
corner at the origin and its upper right back corner at (+1,+1,+1).  The
rectangular image is scaled in the X and Y directions to become a square
one unit on a side (usually making its pixels rectangular rather than
square).

For a Flat projection the texture square is placed into the X-Y plane on
the bottom face of the object cube.  The lower left-hand corner of the
image is at the origin and the upper right-hand corner is at (+1,+1,0).
Each pixel of the texture square projects as a perpendicular rod
(rectangular in cross-section) that extends parallel to the Z-axis
towards infinity in both the +Z and -Z directions.

The problem that arises with rotations is that the axes of rotation are
the texture space coordinate axes which pass through the texture space
origin, not the more convenient axes at the centers of the object and
texture.  So if you want to rotate either the cube or the texture around
its central Z-axis you have to

1. Translate its center to the texture space Z-axis.
2. Perform the rotation around the texture space Z-axis.
3. Translate the center back its original position.

With the Tube projection the image has been wrapped around a vertical
(parallel to the Z-axis) cylinder of irrelevant radius one unit high
centered on (0.5,0.5,0.5).  Each pixel of the image projects
horizontally from the center of the cylinder outwards in an infinite
pie-shaped wedge one pixel high passing exactly through its rectangle on
the surface of the cylinder.

The Sphere projection wraps the image around a sphere of irrelevant
radius centered at (0.5,0.5,0.5).  Each pixel of the image projects from
the center of the sphere outwards to pass exactly through its rectangle
or triangle on the surface of the sphere.

[image: Suzanne stuffed into the cube above flat with cylinder and sphere surrounding]

So rotating the object or the texture about the Z-axis without the extra
translations separates the projected texture and the object, grossly
distorting their intersection.

## Order Of Transforms

The first diversion on the way to the texture mapping model was figuring
out the order in which Blender was executing the transforms from the
Mapping nodes.

It turns out that *within* a Mapping node the transforms are essentially
performed right to left.  The scaling is performed first.  Then the
rotations are performed in Blender's default Euler XYZ order.  Finally
any translations take place.

However the order in which the chain of Mapping nodes is applied depends
upon the choice of Texture vs. Point set in the Mapping nodes.  (Assume
that all Mapping nodes use the same option and ignore Vector and Normal for
present purposes.)

With the default Point selection the Mapping nodes describe how the
object is transformed in texture space while the image projection
remains fixed.  The chain of Mapping nodes is applied left-to-right; the
leftmost Mapping node is applied first, and each Mapping node
transforms the result coming from the node on its left.

With Texture selected the Mapping nodes describe how the texture is
transformed in texture space while the object in its cube remains fixed.
The chain of Mapping nodes is applied right-to-left; the rightmost
Mapping node is applied first, and each mapping node effectively
transforms the result from the node on its right.  (This is the effect,
not how it is actually implemented.)

Point and Texture chains create net transforms which move the object
cube and the texture relative to each other.  Choosing between the two
approaches is a matter of convenience for the user.

## Display Of Materials

The second diversion on the way to the texture mapping model involved
accurate display of the mapped texture.

The Preview display in the Material section of the Properties Editor is
your best friend.  If you are doing transparency or texture mapping you
*need* to have it active.

It did not dawn on me for a while that the 3D View was lying to me about
materials.  I naively assumed that if I set the 3D View's "Viewport
Shading" to Material I would see the actual material.  In fact the only
way to guarantee that is to select Render from the "Method to
display/shade objects in the 3D View:" (Viewport Shading) list.  The
limitation is perfectly understandable in terms of computation time;
using Render can be very slow so Material can be expected to compromise.

But one result is that an Image Texture node set for Clip will show in
the Material selection for the 3D View as if Repeat has been chosen.
*That* was confusing during the early tests.

The other limitation on the Material shading arises directly from
computational expense.  The non-Rendered display methods for the 3D View
cannot display *some* materials (e.g., transparency) on *any* object.
And they cannot display *any* material on *some* objects (e.g., a meta).

## Moral

Do not make assumptions about how Blender works without taking the
time to test those assumptions.