# How can i add more duplicates to a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, dupli-groups

i'm using the [Dupliframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve) method.

But the curve is pretty long compared to the size of the objects, and i need them to be near one of each other.

When i add the maximum number of Frames that is 100, the object appear like this:

[image]

And while i can put them near one with another with a number of frames of 400, the mesh just moves to the first part of the curve, like scaling itself, but i need it in every place of the curve, from the start to the end.

How can i add more duplicates, or tell the option to make them one near the other?

Thanks in regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the amount and density of dupliframes from two different parameters.

Adjust the density of duplicated objects from the number of *Frames* in the Curve Object data > Path Animation > Frames*. A higher number will yield a denser amount of duplicated objects.

If increasing the value high enough gives too few objects to fill the whole curve, then select the duplicated object and under *Object > Duplication* increase the *End Time* value so it fills the whole curve again.

[image]

Comment: That was just what i was looking for! Thank you so much!