# How to make animation like this using array?

Tags: modifiers

How can I make animation like this using array without deforming the shape of the ball? I already tried to make it using array and curve but the balls are deforming when I make the 2nd layer of the curve.
(sorry for my bad english)

[image: it starts with 1 ball]

[image: follows a path][image: until it forms a shape][image: this is the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editing my own post since I can't upvote / comment on the other post by cegaton! (use his answer! it's 10000x better! I didn't know dupliframes existed! :D )

---

hmm, at first, I tried the curve modifier, but this does morph the shape as you specifically requested it shouldn't! (So it's probably the first thing you tried!)

There was another way I 'kinda' got the desired result, or at least, a method that could (with a bit of tweaking), result in the desired output / effect.

That is to turn your path into a mesh (Alt-C), and then apply a particle system to the resultant mesh (you can't make a path itself a particle system). Then you can set the system to:

- emit from verts
- turn of 'random' emission ordering (so they iterate through the verts)
- set lifetime to long enough so that the 'snake' covers the path.

[image]

Lastly, to tweak this, you probably want to 'fix' the mesh that's drawn so that you get evenly spaced vertices (the one i made now was very crude & hand drawn though, using shift + clickdrag in edit mode on the path)

Comment: Tried it and it worked, but the other answer is more easy to use, but still thank you for answering

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an array, what you need is a curve with the shape you want and then use [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html).

To set it up read [How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve)

Then, animate the "duplication end" for the object used along the curve Read: [How can i add more duplicates to a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104916/how-can-i-add-more-duplicates-to-a-curve/104918#104918)

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed, tried it and it worked, i love you :D