# Instancing not working in blender 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves

(*EDIT to reply to duplicate thread suggestion: The reason I think that this thread is not answered in [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve)
is because none of the solutions seem to talk about this feature which is very simple and different to the method used in the thread indicated. The problem is also addressed in [How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve), which does not work for me in 2.8. It seems such a fundamental and simple feature, it deserves to work in 2.8. I suspect I am missing a simple step that you don't need to do in 2.79*)

*(EDIT on problem: Progress: I do seem to get one duplication of the object on top of the instancer, because if I change the evaluation time on the path animation setting, I can see another object on the curve. But just one.)*

My objective is to duplicate an object many times along a curved path without that object distorting. (With array and curve modifiers the object distorts around curves).

I found this video tutorial how to do it in 2.79, and it works fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rp88ckdLwVQ

(Basically it says:
*Click on object you want to repeat then click on the path;
Ctrl+p > follow path;
With the object selected, go to the object properties;
In the duplication section, select frames then unselect speed;
Play with adjustments*

When I try to do the same in 2.8 (although the section is called "instancing" instead of "duplication" it looks like it does the same) I get no joy.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torus object stretched in array curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier)