# How can I follow path in 2.8?

Tags: modeling

We had option to make arrays of objects along curves **without distortion** with follow path option in 2.79. How I can do the same stuff **in 2.8**?

Comment: you mean with the Curve modifier? It caused distortion though... if you don't want to have distortion you need to use the Dupliframes method

Comment: How to use it in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torus object stretched in array curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier)

Comment: sorry I have some bugs with 2.8 when I try to edit a curve, but follow the link that Duarte gave you

Comment: It distorts geometry. I don't need that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve)

Comment: How to do it in 2.8?